# Add A Div around each WordPress post image

Tags: wordpress

I need the ability for all images, placed in a post, to be wrapped in a div so I can add custom styling to the image. (I need a image border on each image.)

How can I get get it so that it automatically adds a div around each image in the post content?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of surrounding each image with a div, why don't you just apply a class to each `<img>` tag?

So, you could add, in your CSS file:

```
img .border
{
/* your border code here */
}
```

And for every image in your HTML, just add `class="border"`.

I would also recommend looking into some CSS3 - `border-image` may offer the solution: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: The issue with that is, I need to add a transparent image as the border. I need to place the transparent image on top of the post image to create the border effect.

Comment: @HuwRowlands Is there no way that you can reproduce the effect with CSS?

Comment: The border (website for a client and designed by someone else!) is a 'grunge' style border.